# Python SQL select row from specific variable field

Tags: python, sql, select

I'd like to grab a specific value from a row based on a random variable.  Here's an example table the PID column is an "auto-increment primary key integer" and the other 2 columns are TEXT

example-table

```
PID    NAME    PHONE
---    ----    -----
1      bill    999-9999
2      joe     888-8888
```

I'd like to throw a random variable at the table

`randomVariable = raw_input('Enter something: ')`

> 1

and have the code return the name

> bill

I know I can use something like...

```
randomVariable = raw_input('Enter something: ')
sql = ("SELECT name FROM example_table WHERE pid='%s'" % randomVariable)
result = cursor.execute(sql)
print result
```

> bill

Apparently using '%s' isn't secure and it is suggested to use '?' in it's place.

```
randomVariable = raw_input('Enter something: ')
sql = ("SELECT name FROM example_table WHERE pid=?", randomVariable)
result = cursor.execute(sql)
print result
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me. I end up with...

> "ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode"

I realize I could just grab all the rows and put them into a variable which I could then iterate over till I find what I'm looking for but I'm thinking that wouldn't be very efficient with a large database. can anyone help point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're meant to use it like this

```
randomVariable = raw_input('Enter something: ')
sql = "SELECT name FROM example_table WHERE pid=?"
result = cursor.execute(sql, randomVariable)
print result
```

Comment: Ah man finally!  I got the result I've been looking for.  This has been one of those programming catchas that I have rarely run into...I just knew the solution was going to be simple.  Thanks cyberkiwi

Answer (score 1):

Validate the user input, and %s is fine. Storing your rows and putting them into a list is not a good idea at **all**, since the amount of rows will grow over time, taking up a huge amount of memory when not even in use. To guard against **SQL injection**, you could validate input using something like a typecast to an int, put that in a try/except block, and this would stop all malicious input such as ' OR 1=1--

Comment: thanks for the input malfry.  Though you lost me at, "you could validate input using something like a typecast to an int,".  I got what I was looking for with cyberkiwis post, but i'm always happy to take advice and improve on my code.  If you wouldn't mind elaborating or posting a link I could learn from I'd appreciate it =)

Comment: Visit the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for info on SQL Injecction. You can typecast something to an int in Python like this:
int(some_user_input)